# Invariant Violation - Unable to import custom component react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

After read through many other similar questions I am still unable to import my custom component.

Here is main view:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Image, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import {LOGO} from '../../assets/logo.png';
import {testingInput} from './testingInput';

function tempScreen({navigation}) {
    return (
        <View style={
            styles.container
        }>
            <View style={
                styles.topContainer
            }>
                <Image styles={
                        styles.logo
                    }
                    scoure={LOGO}
                    resizeMode={'cover'}/>
                <Text>
                    Here
                </Text>
            </View>


            <View style={
                styles.bottomContainer
            }>
                <testingInput/>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    ...
})

export default tempScreen;
```

Here is tempButton File:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {TextInput, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

const testingInput = (prop) => {
    return (
        <TextInput style={
                styles.TextInput
            }
            placeholder="Email"
            color="#ffffff"
            placeholderTextColor="#ffffff"
            autoCapitalize="none"></TextInput>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    TextInput: {

        height: 50,
        flex: 1,
        padding: 10,
        marginLeft: 20
    }
})


export default testingInput;
```

Im getting the error

> "Invariant Violation: View config getter callback for component `testingInput` must be a function (received `undefined`). Make sure to start component names with a capital letter."

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: import TestingInput from './testingInput';
Try this

and make component first latter always capital.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use a default export you do not need destructuring the import.

with `export default testingInput;` you will import `import TestInput from './testinputfile`. Here the name of the import is not important

with `export testingInput;` you will import `import {functionName} from './testinputfile`. Here the name of the import need to be equal to the name of the function exported

Comment: Changing the import help but I also needed to make the first letter capital to fix the issue